# Pass custom controller to angular's directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that looks like this

```
<list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search"></list>
```

and its defined this was:

```
    .directive('list', function($rootScope) {

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
            scope: {
                source:'=',
                search:'=',
                avatarUrl:'='
            }
        }

    })
```

is there any way to specify what controller I want to use inside that directive smth like this:

```
    <list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search" controller="listCtrl"></list>
    <list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search" controller="adminListCtrl"></list>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you have two different functions to call within each controller.

I would do like that:

make div with ng-controller="yourControllerName" and use directive inside
and just pass function name

something like:

```
<div ng-controller="listCtrl">
    <list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search" function-to-call="someFunctionNameInUserList()"></list>
</div>
<div ng-controller="adminListCtrl">
    <list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search" function-to-call="someFunctionNameInAdminListCtrl()"></list>
</div>
```

add functionToCall inside directive:

```
scope: {
    source:'=',
    search:'=',
    avatarUrl:'=',
    functionToCall : '='
}
```

now use functionToCall() inside directive template in ng-click or ng-submit or anywhere you need

Hopefully you got my point. Works in our project fine.

Comment: Actually I would like to specify what controller to use inside my list.html, for example: <div ng-controller="whatControllerToUse">...</div> when I call <list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search" controller="whatControllerToUse"></list>

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a bit of googleing found this solution:

```
.directive('list', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/list.html',
        controller: "@",
        name:'controllerName',
        scope: {
            source:'=',
            search:'=',
            avatarUrl:'='
        }
    }

})

<list source="userList" avatar-url="avatarPath" search="search" controller-name="listCtrl"></list>
```